# ¿Cómo asignar una condición where en caso de que un campo no sea nulo?

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy intentando realizar una consulta copiada de un sqlmap donde tengo lo siguiente:

```
    WHERE COD = mts.origen 
        <isNotNull prepend="AND" property='desde'>
         22 >= TablaPUNTOS.DESDE
         AND (TablaPUNTOS.HASTA > 22 OR TablaPUNTOS.HASTA IS NULL)
        </isNotNull>
```

Copio ese trocito porque concretamente lo que quiero hacer en oracle es lo que sustituiría a <"isNotNul... . Es decir, quiero saber, que si en caso de que desde no fuese nulo, poner la condición AND (y lo que contiene) como ORIGEN.

Espero que me hayan entendido, estoy buscando buscando por internet y he encontrado la función NVL de oracle pero estoy leyendo y pienso que no me sirve pues sustituye valores en consultas cuando son nulos para que no produzca error y esto es diferente a lo que yo quiero hacer. Espero que puedan ayudarme.

Un saludo y gracias.

Finalmente no he conseguido solucionarlo pero porque no analice bien el código sqlmap, lo que pido no se puede hacer y está explicado en los comentarios. Pero la respuesta de Pablo ante mi pregunta es correcta pues NVL hace lo que pedía si hubiese existido ese campo en mi tabla o de al forma que el lo entendio. Dejo la pregunta por si alguna vez le sirve a alguien. Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Quieres que te filtre los registros cuyo TABLAPUNTOS.DESDE sea superior a una fecha concreta sí y sólo sí un parámetro "desde" no es null?

Comment: Exacto, si no es nulo, que me coloque esa condición, si es nulo que pase de ella.

Comment: No me aclaro, lo que quieres es que dado un parámetro "desde", este esté dentro del rango indicado entre TABLAPUNTOS.DESDE y TABLAPUNTOS.HASTA, ¿verdad?

Comment: @pablo mil disculpas, no se puede hacer, analizando el código sqlmap lo que recibe es un parámetro que si dicho parámetro le llega a null va a establecer más condiciones o menos... Simplemente eso, por lo que en base de datos me es imposible poner dicho código porque no existe ese parámetro, es un parámetro creado en un bean y form para comprobar que desde es igual a la versión en la que estoy en dicho momento de hacer la consulta... Te pido disculpas por haberte robado tiempo por no haber analizado antes el otro código... Mil perdones.

Comment: Leído, no pasa nada!

Comment: @pablo finalmente dejo la pregunta porque dicen que me bloquearían el hacer preguntas y como puesto que tu solución es equivalente al título de la pregunta la dejo por si alguien le sirve de ayuda, a mí al menos en ese aspecto me aclaraste para que sirve NVL mejor que lo leído hasta ahora por internet y si existiese el campo en la tabla probablemente funcionaría. Por lo que la dejo por si a alguien le sirve en el futuro. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes cambiarlo y dejarlo así:

```
nvl(desde,to_date('01/01/0001','dd/mm/yyyy'))>= TablaPUNTOS.DESDE
```

De esta forma, si es nulo la condición contra la que compara va a ser siempre true, exactamente igual que no si estuviera incluida.

Comment: Vale, voy a probar, al final entonces si que sirve NVL, gracias por la explicación, no se trata de fechas pero para el ejemplo no importa, voy a probarlo y a ver que tal, de momento tienes tu +, luego verifico si es correcta la respuesta, estamos en contacto. Muchas gracias @pablo

Comment: Que va no me sirve... Creo que me debo enterar mejor de esto...

Comment: ¿Cómo lo has dejado?

Comment: Pues he probado de varias formas porque a como yo lo quiero asignar como tu lo has puesto no lo entendía muy bien, actualizo la pregunta para que lo puedas ver mejor @pablo

Comment: Ya está editado, debo enterarme mejor de lo de NVL porque creo que mi problema lo tengo en la sintaxis sino no se que debe estar pasando, porque es una consulta super larga y lo mismo el error aunque me lo indique en la parte del primer 22, puede ser que venga de antes que muchas veces me ha pasado... @pablo